# is it possible to use asp.net page level caching with vary by param and localization

Tags: asp.net, caching

I would like to use page level caching on my asp.net page.  vary by param works fine - however, the page content is cached in the language of the original request.  If the same url / param is requested and the user is viewing in a different locale than the first request (French instead of English for example) - the cache returns the page content in the original request's language (English).  Is there a way to cache the page based on the vary by param and a value in the base page class (like as the property value returned from Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the OutputCache set the  `VaryByCustom="Language"` and update you Global.asax file to override the HttpApplication.GetVaryByCustomString Method by adding the following code:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
    {
        if (custom.Equals("Language"))
        {
            return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
        }
    }
```

This code will make the parameter that the cache depends on is your page culture.

Comment: I used this code,first time language changes to other. but then, not switch back first language..

Comment: This code is used to allow caching depending on the language used and not for changing the language so there might be a problem in the language switching logic that this function depends on.

Comment: and how can you help me about my question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653343/outputcache-not-let-to-change-site-language ?

Answer (score 1):

With datacache you can specify the cache name. what I did when I had this problem I caches the pagedata with pagename + localisation as cachename