# OutputCache not let to change site language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, localization, outputcache

I want to use OutputCache to open pages quickly.

I wrote in controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
[OutputCache(Duration=3600,VaryByParam="none", VaryByCustom="lang")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   //........
 }

public ActionResult ChangeCulture( string lang, string returnUrl )
{
  Session["Culture"] = new CultureInfo( lang );
  return Redirect( returnUrl );
}
}
```

In Layout.cshtml:

```
<a href="@Url.Action( "ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "en", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl } )">Eng</a>
<a href="@Url.Action( "ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "az", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl } )">Az</a>
```

In Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
//It's important to check whether session object is ready
if ( HttpContext.Current.Session != null )
{
CultureInfo ci = ( CultureInfo )this.Session["Culture"];

//Checking first if there is no value in session and set default language this can happen for first user's request
if ( ci == null )
{
//Sets default culture to english invariant
string langName = "az";

//Try to get values from Accept lang HTTP header
if ( HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null &&
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.Length != 0 )
{
//Gets accepted list 
langName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Substring( 0, 2 );
}
ci = new CultureInfo( langName );
this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
}
//Finally setting culture for each request
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( ci.Name );
}
}

public override string GetVaryByCustomString( HttpContext context, string value )
{
if ( value.ToLower() == "lang" )
{
return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
}
return base.GetVaryByCustomString( context, value );
}
```

But I cannot change site language. For example, I switch language to English, It changes, but then want to return Azerbaijan language, it did not changes. What is my mistake?  (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: How are you differentiating between languages?  Parameters?  For example (/en-us/controller/action) or some other way?  Basically you need to use the VaryBy(?) attribute of the OutputCache to cache different languages

Comment: I use this action in home controller:  

        public ActionResult ChangeCulture( string lang, string returnUrl )
        {
            Session["Culture"] = new CultureInfo( lang );
            return Redirect( returnUrl );
        }
  
and 
 
 protected void Application_AcquireRequestState( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {} 
method in Global.asax.
Please share any sample link about using VaryBy(?) attribute. I want to make OutputCache not save language resources.

Comment: I found a link

http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved myself, changed

```
<globalization culture="en" uiCulture="en" />
```

to

```
 <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

in config file. Then it worked.